# Word Count Hadoop Example

Tags: hadoop

I am running word count ex on a 41 GB file ( with default configuration setting ) that comes with Hadoop( Version:  0.20.3-dev) . But this code is giving correct output for the small file but it is giving some garbage for the  41 GB file. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Check your input file.. check by manually computing it and you would realize its not garbage.

Comment: MY OUTPUT FILE CONTENT =====>      �)<Em���Z���$�G]�Lܔ��(����P)O�r6�l_�}�Ƅ9�{INB4r���{"O 180
�/�=�: 180
�0�$gUh�$^!�0st^ڕu6���k��pJ����,��+�[^��]����� 180
�;�B 180
�>۲v����L��Q��Q�Yk^� 180
�XL�| 180
�]�و��R��Z���T<w0�Ҩ��R�8�9�N�e\�`��; 180
�aGUF����I+С���|橜+*L�~�ؘ}����I�L�Maa,뎤nG���5u��̭h��v�Ne�ͥ����_Wo0}Z��՛��@��^�Û�m�g���Ӗ7������SK�:������Ż7� 180
�f���¯���ǧ%g���Dɬ�Ẍ��Ff���X'�o8����LyG�n�������a���-�T�!� 180
�mjׄK|y�u��1;�"�:}��W���F�!���l�WR�=爼Q��^z�U(fhNp�]�1��~�,%����U�)����x���j�� 180    ..... I Do not know how to interpret it ?

Comment: It is standard word count example that comes with Hadoop( hadoop-0.20.2-examples.jar).

Comment: Do you have enough space?

Comment: Yes, more then enough ..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everybody.It may create wrong output because Hadoop by default does not know your file format it treats every file as a simple text file.